# SPecJVM2008 compiled with JDK-1.4

Tags: jvm

We are trying to do benchmarking of JVM on our system using SPECJVM2008. It is seen that the pre-compiled Specjvm2008.jar is compiled with a higher version than JDK 1.4 but my system will understand only JDK-1.4 or lower. I looked out for procedure to compile SPECJVM2008 for my target but could not find any. Can anyone help me to cross-compile SPECJVM2008 ? Thanks.

Comment: SpecJVM2008 will not support JDK-1.4 b'cos it is written using JDK-1.5 and later and is not backward compatible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SpecJVM2008 will not support JDK-1.4 b'cos it is written using JDK-1.5 and later and is not backward compatible

Answer (score 0):

I refer you to [retrotranslator](http://retrotranslator.sourceforge.net/)

Executing:

```
java -jar retrotranslator-transformer-1.2.9.jar -srcjar SPECjvm2008.jar -destjar SPECjvm2008_14.jar -embed com.mycompany.internal
```

produces a JDK 1.4 compatible jar with SPECjvm2008.